# Xubuntu Terminal overrides shell- and vi color schemes, how to deactivate?

Tags: terminal, colors, xfce, xubuntu

I'm running an up-to-tade Xubuntu and have a real problem with these Terminals. I don't want them to be all that design-ish. Just the plain old Terminal with a black background and green text. And in VIM I want to use my own color scheme. But the xfce-4-terminal doesn't seem to let me do that. It always uses it's own color schemes and they just don't work for all cases (you have like 6 different types of text elements to color, for coding you need more).

How can I disable the coloring in the terminal or just load a simple one without all these features?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The distro overriding the colors of the terminal and vim are a horrible idea.  To disable this "feature" edit the file: /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/Terminal/terminalrc  place the '#' character in front of any line you wish to disable (I did all but the first two).

Comment: emptying the `~/.config/Terminal/terminalrc` did the job for me. Thanks